# Linq distinct for 1 column

Tags: c#, linq

I am currently getting a distinct list of data. Properties are **MDMMappingCode** which is unique and **CustNameReporting** which can have duplicate data.

Data being returned:

[image]

From my linq query the data being returned is correct but I only need 1 unique **CustNameReporting** instead of 5 being repeated. This issue I am facing is the **MDMMappingCode** is different. What should I change in my linq query to take the first record.

Code

```
List<OptionDto> customers = await _appDbContext.MasterDataCustomerActivityGrids
                                    .Select(e => new OptionDto() { Value = e.MDMMappingCode, Label = e.CustNameReporting })
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .OrderBy(e => e.Label)
                                    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

public class OptionDto
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, you need to define *which* record you want. The lowest MDMMappingCode? The highest? Any random one?

Comment: Any random one @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: Then you'll need to group by CustNameReporting and then select the `First()` from the group to get the MDMMappingCode. Try to play around a bit first, then there are multiple solutions online :)

Comment: Duplicate of [LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property) (read past the accepted answer for different solutions).